# QTP launches and then abruptly get closed when invoked through RQM Commandline Adapter

Tags: qtp, qtplugin

Settings:
QTP 11.0
RQM Adapter ver : com.ibm.rqm.adapter.commandline_2.0.0.v20140416_2010

RQM adapter calls the batch file, which invokes scriptlaunch.vbs program to launch qtp script.

QTP launches and then abruptly gets closed, however the process QTPro.exe is still active on the taskmanger for  1-2 minutes after which it ends when qtp fails to look solution for the problem on the web.

For many past months we have successfully carried out execution this way, however from very recent we are running into this issue.

This issue is seen after we took a Citrix remote login of the system where qtp script execution was going on via RQM CLA.
when the remote login was taken we saw some error and after that we are unable to get the execution done through RQM CLA.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your system recently which might causing the issue?

Comment: Except for CITRIX VDA software installation.......no changes have been made